# Tried to change author name in Netbeans and now I can't commit to Github

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Let me start of saying that I'm a beginner and don't know much about Github and Java. I'm also using Netbeans. Right now I'm doing the Helsinki MOOC Java Open Course that some of you might be familiar with. I could commit the code and upload to Github easily, but then I noticed that the Author name in Netbeans was different from my Github name and I tried to change this by changing the name in Git.properties file to the same name as on Github, and now I get errors everytime I try to upload new code to Github, even though I have tried reinstalling Netbeans and deleting the git.properties file. To make things easier for you, check my uploaded pictures of the errors I'm getting. How can I fix this?

[image: Repository]

Git push failed

[image: Git push failed]

Merge commit needed

[image: Merge commit needed]

Resolve conflicts

[image: Resolve conflicts]

Resolve Conflicts2

[image: Resolve Conflicts2]

Comment: To prevent resolve conflict you can use the "push --force" command but as I understand what is going on you changed your installed git software username which github will determine your new user as someone other than your github user and the problem might on that you change the username and all your commits registered as someone other than who github registered your previous commits so there are some conflict and you must change the email and username to previous one

Answer (score 0):

It is an option in some java IDEs including eclipse and netbeans which automatically makes a document for your class ,interface etc.
These IDEs use a variable called user in the follow of @author property in class document.
Your problem starts when the user value equals to your current OS username that you login in it.
To prevent "netbeans" to write the OS username as default author name you can go to tools > templates.
after click on templates a dialog will be showed which include some folders like WEB,JAVA,JAVAFX etc.
In every folder we have some files like "Java class","Java Interface" etc which are your default shortcuts when you want to create a new item like an interface or a class , enum etc.
These files are your default templates for instance when you right click on a package > new > java class it make a java class in that package and its content is based on tools > templates > java > java class.
All you must do is to change every shortcut you want like java class or interface by open up tools > templates > java  and click on java class or interface then click on open in editor button then search for somewhere like @author ${user} you must change the ${user} to your github username as the following example :
from :

```
/**
@author ${user}
*/
```

to :

```
/**
@author Swedishnovice
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have managed to change the author name but I can't commit any projects to Github anymore.

I tried pulling from Github first, and then pushing, then I got the following message: "Merge of HEAD with origin/master failed. For more information see the output. " How do I fix this?